# Django internationalization not working while DEBUG = True in zinnia blog app

Tags: django, internationalization, zinnia

one of those things that need some grasp of django internals which I still lack. I'm testing a blogging app zinnia (http://django-blog-zinnia.com/). With DEBUG = False I get my website without static assets (locally, this I can understand), with DEBUG = True, it's ok with static, but translations don't  work i.e. website is not rendered in my chosen language. I use stock development server (runserver). Why? Anyone so kind to explain?:)

Relevant parts of settings.py:

```
gettext = lambda s: s

DEBUG = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'locale'))

USE_I18N = True

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'

DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 1

LANGUAGES = (
    ('pl', gettext('Polish')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ---snip--- )
```

Comment: Could you post the language and localization related settings in your `settings.py`?

Comment: Do you have the Locale middleware as well? `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` must be added yo tour `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and it must go after the `SessionMiddleware`.

Comment: @AdriánLópez, thx, but yep, I have it in place, and yet it doesn't work as expected;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the source of your problem, but your `LOCALE_PATHS` setting looks wrong to me. It is supposed to be a tuple, whereas yours results in a string. And it's not an absolute path.

Try something like this instead:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
   os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'locale')),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it looked wrong to me also:) I did change it, that doesn't seem to be the the source of the problem though.